# connecting delphi to oracle and retrieve data

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi

I'm a beginer in Delphi. I have followed the tutorial in [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSHUejL-lHg). this is my 1st lesson. I want to retrieve data from oracle with delphi 7. my script like this :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, DB, ADODB;

type
  TForm_Test = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection_main: TADOConnection;
    qryTable_test: TADODataSet;
    dsTable_test: TDataSource;
    dbgTable_test: TDBGrid;
    btnUpload: TButton;
    procedure btnUploadClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form_Test: TForm_Test;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm_Test.btnUploadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form_Test.qryTable_test.SQL.Clear;
  Form_Test.qryTable_test.SQL.Add('Select * from table');
  Form_Test.qryTable_test.Active:=true;
end;


end.
```

**get error :**

`[Error] Unit1.pas[34]: Undeclared identifier: 'SQL'` in Line `Form_Test.qryTable_test.sql.clear;`

What can i do?

Comment: try changing qryTable_test to TADOQuery rather than a TADODataSet

Comment: Hint: avoid the instance reference (Form_Test) in methods of the class (TForm_Test): use `qryTable_test.SQL` instead of `Form_Test.qryTable_test.SQL`

Comment: Using `TADODataSet`, which I would prefer too, `CommandText` would be the needed property.